# CodeIgniter 500 server error when uploading to remote host, fine on local

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get a 500 server error when I upload my CodeIgniter files online.

> #### 500 Server Error
>
> A misconfiguration on the server caused a hiccup. Check the server logs, fix the problem, then try again.

Locally, it works perfectly. I don't know what's wrong when I upload it.

I updated the config files and everything. What am I doing wrong?

CodeIgniter has a lot of files, so I don't know if there is something specific you want to see?

This is whats inside the .htaccess file

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
```

Comment: the second line in the error message tells you what to see. Check your server error log. You need not check codeigniter in this stage

Comment: what does your error log say? there could be something turned off that is required by codeigniter (usually you can turn this back on in php.ini unless you're on a shared host)

Comment: I checked the server logg. Its too long and I don't understand a thing

Comment: @ray023: How would that help? CI hasn't even had a chance to run the bootstrap yet!

Comment: @Kay: Post the contents of your .htaccess file in the question. It's probably related.

Comment: @Kay post the last 10 lines or so of the error log. also check that the file permissions are correct and the owner too. I've often had to CHMOD uploaded files after working offline. YMMV.

Comment: @Madmartigan I cant fins the .htaccess where is it?

Comment: @Madmartigan i posted the .htaccess file in the post

Answer (score 1):

Check your hosting company to make sure they run PHP5 and not PHP4.  I had this problem with 1and1.com where you had to change your .htaccess file to force the use of PHP5.  That solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I realized a bizarre issue. If your version of php is 5.4.3 on an ubuntu server (10.04) and you are using the mysqli extension, you would have problems. enable error reporting in your script to pinpoint the errors. This particular version does not support mysqli